# Excel and lists with Python

Tags: python, import-from-excel

I am treating Excel sheets using Python.
I wrote this :

```
import xlrd
wb=xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Inputs_UNF_newForm.xlsx')
s=wb.sheet_by_name('Chemical treatments')

def getOutputs(s):
    for row_index in range(28):
        v = s.cell_value(row_index, 1)
        if s.cell_value(row_index, 1) != "" :
            print ('"'+v +'"'+","),

getOutputs(s)
```

It works just fine. (Well, except that there is still a coma after the last word..)
The thing is, I need to create a list of the result of the getOuputs fonction, ie. a list of the cells I read.

I did this:

```
OutputList=[getOutputs(s)]
print OutputList[1]
```

But it didn't work. What am I missing? (The extra coma?)

Comment: `getOutputs` *doesn't return anything* (or rather, will implicitly return `None`), so you should not be surprised by this. Even if it *did* return something, there would **never** be an `OutputList[1]`, because list indices are zero-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are just printing the values instead of returning them.  Here I use an originally empty list `keep` and append the values to the `keep` list, then return that list to the caller.

```
def getOutputs(s):
    keep = []
    for row_index in range(28):
        v = s.cell_value(row_index, 1)
        if v != "" :
            keep.append(v)
    return keep
```

On a side note, an easy way to deal with printing the values without the trailing comma would then be `print(",".join(OutputList)).

Comment: Thank you for your return. I used your solution and I added a `print(getOuputs(s)` and got `[u'item1', u'item2', u'item3']` What does the 'u' mean?